# how to get sub string index in python

Tags: python, regex

substring_list = ['good to have', 'must have','plus','must']

mystr = '''C++ C, Standard Template Library, IOStreams, String Library and C++ Standard containers, the C Library
C++, C#, Microsoft .NET frameworks, Winforms, WPF, Infragistics, TFS
Inter-language integration, REST
Must be very familiar with modern versions of Oracle databas SQL.
good to have Core Java, Collections, multi-threading, Spring, JSON.
Excellent communication skills.
Familiarity with modern full software development lifecycle practices'''

for w in substring_list:

## how to get the indexes of substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mystr.find(w)
```

That will return the index of the first instance of the found substring, or `-1` if the substring isn't found. For example for the first substring it will return 271. And you could use `mystr[271:]` tor retrieve the string at that index on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for x in substring_list:
    y = mystr.find(x)
    if y != -1:
        print("found: ", x, "at ", y)
```

Output

> ('found: ', 'good to have', 'at ', 271)

More about `find` [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: OP means the indices of the strings in `mystr`.

Comment: sub_string index value in string?

Comment: It does not have the end position of the string but only the start index.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the list, find the start and end position and then display. You can build on this.

```
    substring_list = ['good to have', 'must have','plus','must']

    mystr = "C++ C, Standard Template Library, IOStreams, String Library and C++ Standard containers, the C Library C++, C#, Microsoft .NET frameworks, Winforms, WPF, Infragistics, TFS Inter-language integration, REST Must be very familiar with modern versions of Oracle databas SQL. good to have Core Java, Collections, multi-threading, Spring, JSON. Excellent communication skills. Familiarity with modern full software development lifecycle practices"

    for i in substring_list:
        if i in mystr:
            start=mystr.find(i)
            end=start + len(i)
            print('Substring found: "%s" Start: %s End %s' %(mystr[start:end], start, end))
        else:
            print('Substring not found: "%s" ' %(i))
```

The output is like the following:

```
     Substring found: "good to have" Start: 271 End 283
     Substring not found: "must have"
     Substring not found: "plus"
     Substring not found: "must"
```

Comment: thankyou@MichalelR small doubt how to get 40 indices after the sub string

Comment: You can create an array and then add each occurrence of the string